# Understanding SenTestingKit Log Output

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, sentestingkit

I am trying fully understand the final console output generated from my unit tests:

```
Test Suite 'Multiple Selected Tests' finished at 2013-02-21 22:54:57 +0000.
Executed 6 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.034 (0.052) seconds
```

most of it self explanatory, but the last I am unsure about. Specifically `in 0.034 (0.052) seconds`. It can't be an average because each test shows output like the following:

```
Test Suite 'MMProductLogicTests' started at 2013-02-21 22:54:57 +0000 Test Case
-[MMProductLogicTests testProductMissingFormURL]' started.
Test Case '-[MMProductLogicTests testProductMissingFormURL]' passed (0.005 seconds).
Test Suite 'MMProductLogicTests' finished at 2013-02-21 22:54:57 +0000.
```

All six tests show `passed (0.005 seconds)` so an average does not make sense. `0.034` appears to be the total time for executing, I am confused about  what `(0.052)` represents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.034 is the 'testDuration'; 0.052 is the 'totalDuration'.

Here is the SenTestingKit source code (older version):

```
   + (void) testSuiteDidStop:(NSNotification *) aNotification
    {
        SenTestRun *run = [aNotification run];
        testlog ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Suite '%@' finished at %@.\nPassed %d test%s, with %d failure%s (%d unexpected) in %.3f (%.3f) seconds\n",
            [run test],
            [run stopDate],
            [run testCaseCount], ([run testCaseCount] != 1 ? "s" : ""),
            [run totalFailureCount], ([run totalFailureCount] != 1 ? "s" : ""),
            [run unexpectedExceptionCount],
            [run testDuration],
            [run totalDuration]]);
    }
```

Unfortunately further examination of the code does not reveal the differences between the two.